# Selenium Python StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid. My table is not printing all the column values

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am printing out a table's column values. There are 5 columns.  I print out  Name, Dataset and Datamap col values.

```
col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0] # This is the Name column
col_dataset = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1] # This is the Dataset column
col_datamap = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2] # This is the Datamap
print col_name.text
print col_dataset.text
print col_datamap.text
```

I was getting list index out of range error at first.  I then put print len(rows) so i can find out what was happening.  Only 1 column was being printed.
By using print len(rows) I found out that it was getting only 1 column the 
I think the other 4 columns have not been drawn, rendered yet.  Page not completed.

The 2nd time my method gets called (from TestCase 2), there is a 2nd row in the table.  It prints the column length 5 which is correct and all the values gets printed.

The dev says wait for the page to be completed or wait until all the elements have loaded.
I tried to put time.sleep(10) before i call the following line of code:

```
time.sleep(10)
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
```

Inside the for loop I have also tried WebdriverWait, the following line of code:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```

I get the following error Element is not longer valid:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

Here is the method which I am calling to print out the column values from the table:

```
    def get_feeds_col_values(self):
    try:
        table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0')
        time.sleep(10)
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        #wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #element = wait.until(self.driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete")
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
        print "Rows length"
        print len(rows)
        for row in rows:
            #time.sleep(10)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
            print "cols length"
            print len(row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td"))
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0] # This is the Name column
            col_dataset = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1] # This is the Dataset column
            col_datamap = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2] # This is the Datamap
            print col_name.text
            print col_dataset.text
            print col_datamap.text
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
       print "NoSuchElementException" + e
```

TestCase 1 which calls the method:

```
def test_add_crm_feeds(self):
    print "*** Test add crm feeds ***"
    data_dashboard_page = self.login_page.userLogin_valid(Globals.login_username, Globals.login_password)
    md = main_dashboard.MainDashboardPage(self.driver)
    md.select_project_from_drop_down()
    data_configuration_page = data_dashboard_page.click_data_configuration2() # Click Data Configuration from the Project Navigator
    assert data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed(), "Data Configuration Page not displayed"
    if data_configuration_page.is_Data_Configuration_pageDisplayed():
       print "ERROR - Data Configuration page is not displayed"
    projectNavigator = project_navigator.ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
    feedsPage = projectNavigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Feeds")
    self.assertTrue(feedsPage.is_feeds_pageDisplayed(), "Feeds page not showm. We have not landed on the correct Feeds page.  See error log for details")
    if not feedsPage.is_feeds_pageDisplayed():
        print "ERROR - Feeds page is not displayed"
    feedsPage.click_add_feeds()
    feedsPage.enter_feed_name("crm") # Enter crm for the feeds name
    feedsPage.select_datamap_from_dropdown()
    feedsPage.select_dataset_from_dropdown("CRM")
    feedsPage.click_fields_tab()
    feedsPage.select_preview_to_import_fields_drop_down(Globals.datapreview_crm_name)
    if not feedsPage.is_crmid_checkbox_selected():
        print "CRMID checkbox is not checked by default - Going to click it"
        feedsPage.click_crmid_checkbox()
    feedsPage_saved = feedsPage.click_save2()
    feedsPage_saved.get_feeds_col_values()
```

TestCase 2 which calls the method:

```
def test_add_escr_feeds(self):
    print "*** Test add escr feeds ***"
    projectNavigator = project_navigator.ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
    feedsPage = projectNavigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Feeds")
    feedsPage.click_add_feeds()
    feedsPage.enter_feed_name("escr") # Enter escr for the feeds name
    feedsPage.select_datamap_from_dropdown()
    feedsPage.select_dataset_from_dropdown("ESCR")
    feedsPage.click_fields_tab()
    feedsPage.select_preview_to_import_fields_drop_down(Globals.datapreview_escr_name)
    if not feedsPage.is_crmid_checkbox_selected():
        print "ESCRID checkbox is not checked by default - Going to click it"
        feedsPage.click_crmid_checkbox()
    feedsPage_saved = feedsPage.click_save2()
    feedsPage_saved.get_feeds_col_values()
```

Some help appreciated to solve this issue.
Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible after script execution internal ids of elements changed and webdriver can not find old rows in new DOM tree. Check this hypothesis:

```
table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0')    
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
print table_id.id, [row.id for row in rows] # initial ids of elements
for row in rows:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
    table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'data_configuration_feeds_ct_fields_body0')        
    rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    print table_id.id, [row.id for row in rows] # after script execution
```

Comment: The table ID in the table was changing so it couldn't find old elements in the DOM tree.  The dev has removed the number now and I have got it working now.  Thanks for the hypothesis, it helped me in identifying what was happening.